# Calculus Based Microeconomics Book

Tags: microeconomics

This is more of an informal question. I am studying microeconomics theory and have completed the intermediate microeconomics by Hal R.Varian. I really enjoyed the book and want to upgrade my skills. So please suggest me some good books that would serve the purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to go step above Varian's intermediate microeconomics and you like Varian as an author then his book Microeconomic Analysis is on graduate level.

However, I personally prefer more  Mas-Colell,  Whinston, and Green (MWG) Microeconomic theory. That is probably the most comprehensive microeconomics textbook there is on the market.

Comment: Alright, Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: And once one is done with MWG, he or she can move on to Microeconomic Foundations I by Kreps. :P